# Could marble sized bombs which detonate on impact (launched with slings) replace muskets in warfare?

Tags: science-based, weapons, medieval, ancient-history, renaissance

I'm trying to build a sort of prime directive violated medieval or ancient society, where outside forces have influenced the development of their warfare. But the outsiders are reluctant to trade in guns, but they trade in something akin to bang snaps, but much much more explosive.

Would this (or a similar marble sized bomb) make a significant change to development in warfare, or would it be quickly abandoned?

Are there existing types of serious small explosives I can reference which could fit this description?

Comment: [Nytroglycerin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitroglycerin). BTW, muskets became important on the batttlefield in the late 16th century. *Cannon*, on the other hand, came into use much earlier, initially as siege weapons.

Comment: A collection of random facts: One of the last recorded uses of slings in military action was during the Spanish civil war. Grenadiers used slings to throw hand grenades with better range and precision. Today's smart guns are also capable of firing grenades that fit the description of your munitions. The Aztec slings were comparable in effectiveness to Cortez' muskets, per the accounts of Cortez, without explosive shot.

Comment: You should link, or even better, explain `prime directive`. You might also want to link `snaps`, as a simple search, at least for me, points to alcoholic beverages which I do not assume to be what you meant...

Answer (score 7):

I think what you would get is something to replace the [rifle grenade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rifle_grenade#Modern_use) or [grenade launcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grenade_launcher). Historically there were [grenadier units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grenadier), who were considered [elite units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grenadier#Early_distinctions_of_dress_and_equipment) because of the need to select tall, strong, dexterous men who could handle grenades safely and throw them wide enough to escape their fragments.

The use of a sling for grenades increases the possible range and reduces the need to select for strength, but it adds another thing which can lead to a fumble and a grenade exploding in their own ranks.

Historical grenades detonated with a burning fuse (or became duds when the fuses were extinguished. Imagine a ceramic grenade body, perhaps with some lead sling bullets glued on to create extra fragmentation and filled with black powder. The imported gadget is a crude *impact fuse* for them.

- With those ingredients, the locals still lack the barrels to make a functioning firearm. Clay pots and lead balls were mass-produced in Greek and Roman times. A barrel which does not burst is another ballgame.
- They could of course use the black powder for blasting purposes, e.g. in a [mine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_warfare) under a castle wall.

Introducing this might be a significant advance over a Roman-style line of soldiers with javelins and swords. It would be replaced once they figure out how to build a musket, but that might be decades, even centuries, depending on the starting point of their metalworking.

Answer (score 3):

If the weapon you describe is going to replace other weapons, it needs to have an advantage over them. I'm going to assume there is a possibility of guns being developed eventually, otherwise there would be no question.
Several criteria in which we can compare the weapons suggested and what was historically developed:

- How effective are they in combat?
  Your weapon would obviously be out-classed by modern weapons, but in a "medieval or ancient society" that could would be a very powerful choice in battle. Just compare it to the other ranged weapons used by medieval societies like crossbows and long-bows and it's clear that an exploding ammo could be superior (also remember you can have small units wielding those to scatter large forces so your archers can snipe at single targets).
- How easy are they to use?
  Ease of usage is not just important in the battle. If you're training an army you want to spend as little time as possible with a recruit before you can send him out to battle. If using this small bomb weapon is easier then using a bow, that can be a very significant reason to for military leaders to opt for it.
- Price.
  Similar to the point of ease of usage, money is always a huge incentive. You say that societies are only sold your type of weapon, that means it's much harder to find different options. An interesting twist can be corruption. Have those "outsiders" bribe world leaders into choosing their weapons. (or just make it cheaper).

#### Let's summarize:

If you want a realistic way of convincing your audience that it makes sense that those marble-bombs are so prevalent in your world, or that they have replaced weapons that would otherwise be developed, you need to give your audience simple and clear reasons. If you need to explain this, you can spend a few paragraphs on how the decision to invest in those was made, and have military leaders raise the arguments you have.

Comment: I think that slings would be a bad idea, as they take years to train with. Explosive crossbow bolts on the other hand would be much more effective due to ease of training, cost effectiveness (you only need to change ammo, you don't need to replace your old crossbows), and much further range. And once the presumably expensive explosive ammo runs out, you can switch back to cheap, normal ammo.

Answer (score 2):

First, you absolutely can use slings to throw grenades and it will significantly improve range, which I hear is a good thing.

But if you are thinking of replacing muskets by using explosives to make sling bullets more lethal that probably will not work.

Two reasons:

First, slings are already quite lethal. A normal non-explosive sling bullet is dense enough and flies fast enough to stop most targets it hits. Shields and armor help but the issue with slings never was the damage being too small. You could provide bullets made of depleted uranium if you want...

Second, the issue with slings was that it takes practice to be good with them. Generally slingers were from mountainous areas where they grew up using slings to deter predators from eating their sheep. Everybody else used bows since training somebody to hit a target with a bow is much easier.

Up until bows were themselves replaced by muskets due to it being so much easier to train somebody to hit a target with a musket... So no, giving slings more damage probably will not replace muskets or even bows.